# To lower case recursive algorithm

Tags: recursion, pascal

I have this code for returning a string in all lower case, using recursion:

```
function min(ch:string):string;
begin
    if ( ch = '' ) then
      min:= ''
    else
      if (ch[1] in ['A'..'Z']) then
        begin
          ch[1]:=chr(ord(ch[1])+32);
          min:= ch[1] + min(copy(ch,2,length(ch)-1));
        end;
end;
```

But it doesn't work:

When I run it with the example `min('AbC')` the output is `a` only not `abc`.

Where is the problem here?

Comment: How does it not work? What happens when you run it?

Comment: *it doesn't work* is not a meaningful problem description. How exactly does it *not work*? Do you get compiler errors? If so, what are they **exactly**? Does it compile, but produce output different than you expect? If so, what input did you provide and output did you expect, and what did you get instead?

Comment: And, what **exactly** are you expecting it to do?

Comment: haven't used pascal in a while, but aren't you missing the END of the second if-statement?

Comment: @ThomasD: Where is the `begin` that you expecting this `end` to match?

Comment: @MartynA good point... i thought it also matches against THEN

Comment: i fixed the code it was missing the begin and end; 
when i compile it with the exemple min('ABC') the output is 'a' only not 'abc' where is the problem here !

Comment: Btw, `ch` is a bad choice for the name of a `string` parameter,  `ch` is most often used to denote a `Char1` parameter or variable.

Comment: You didn't fix your code in the question. You need to [edit] to fix the code and add the problem description **in the question itself**, not in comments.

Comment: code updated ! i want to transform a string like 'AbC' to 'abc' recursively

Comment: i feel like i can't solve any problem recursively !!

Comment: You **still have not edited your post to describe the problem you're having with the code**. We can't help you if you're not willing to help yourself by cooperating with requests here. To make it clear: **Edit your question to explain the problem you're having with the code in the question, not in comments.**

Comment: One remark: I guess this is to get you acquainted with recursion. I guess that works (if you get it solved). Otherwise, it is not a very performant way to convert a string to lowercase, because for each iteration, two strings are being copied around: the destination and the tail. A simple loop would be a lot faster. In other languages, which use pointers to chars, the performance hit is probably far less significant.

Comment: i was just practising recursion ! i knew how to to solve it iteratively. ty for the remark !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not always call the recursive function. As soon as you find a letter that is already lower case, you don't look any more at the characters that follow it. And so the return value is truncated up to that character.

You should also call it when the character being looked at is *not* a capital letter. So move the recursive call out of that `if`, and it will work:

```
function min(ch:string):string;
begin
    if ( ch = '' ) then
      min:= ''
    else
      begin 
        if (ch[1] in ['A'..'Z']) then
            ch[1]:=chr(ord(ch[1])+32);
        min:= ch[1] + min(copy(ch,2,length(ch)-1));
      end;
end;
```

See it run on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/8cSKyq).